# I'm unable to verify my email in Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

I cant verify my email on Pokemon Go. If I click on 'Verify your email' they send me to [this page](https://club.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-trainer-club/activated/765a974bfeb8464f072de3fe9339c439) and apparently my account isn't activated.

Somebody know what to do?

Comment: What way did you sign up?

Comment: It's most likely because their website is down/overloaded.

Answer (score 1):

There are currently issues with the Pokemon Club, due to server overload.

Having previously attempted to create an account multiple times across separate devices and internet source, to confirm a comment on an answer I posted, I found that the servers can not even handle account creation at the present time..

This is not surprising, given that the general Pokemon Go servers have had major issues with being overloaded.

Unfortunately, your problem is most likely a result of issues on their side. If this is the case, you will just have to wait for the developers to implement a fix on their side.

That said, **you do not need a Pokemon Club membership to play Pokemon Go**. If you wish to play without the wait<sup>1</sup>, just log in using your Google ID.

<sub><sup>1</sup> You will, of course, have other server issues during your experience. This is a known problem, and there is not much we can do about it but wait. If you encounter server issues *in-game*, close the application, wait five minutes, and try again.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with an updated version which stopped Pokemon Club accounts from working. Try updating the app or alternatively log in with a Google account.

Comment: Do you have any source for this? A source would likely list the version number where this was an issue, and make it easier for users to identify if they could be encountering that problem